# How do I test game center

Tags: ios, testing, game-center

How do I test game center before I release my app? the apple guide requires it to be on iTunes Connect, but as I understand it, iTunes Connect is only for released apps, and right now I am in Ad Hoc beta testing.

Answer (score 0):

Just use it -- from an ad hoc game you will automatically be signed into the sandbox version of Game Center.

(This can be a little confusing, though at least in iOS the Game Center app shows you that you're in the sandbox. Also, the Game Center app is the only way you can log out of the sandbox and back into regular Game Center.)

Comment: It does say "Sandbox" when it asks to create account, but it says the app is not recognized when I try to log in later

Comment: You do need to enable stuff in iTunesConnect…

Comment: how can I enable it in iTunesConnect without releasing the app?

Comment: Just don't submit a binary. Do all the configuring as if you're going live.

Comment: it asks for availability date... what if I don't know it?

Comment: and if I decide to release it tomorrow, will they let me change it? they also ask for descriptions, pictures, icons and stuff, can I just give them junk and change it later?

Comment: Yes. Really, it's not that complicated. Ignore the screen shots and metadata until you're ready to release, or put in junk if you need to.